# Finding bottleneck in TCP connection

Tags: linux, windows, sockets, networking, tcp

I am working on a project that has one publisher and one subscriber, connected via a regular TCP socket connection. The publisher generates messages at a certain rate, sends them over the socket, then the subscriber processes the messages. No message queue, just pure TCP socket connection.

The issue is that the socket "write" method in the publisher seems to take a long time when called, and this is reducing the rate at which the publisher can send data.

I have been doing some reading on sockets, and can think of two scenarios that might cause this:

1. The network is not fast enough to handle sending the message send rate. In this case I think the socket outbound buffer on the publisher should be filled up.
2. The consumer is slow processing the messages, and hence I would expect the inbound buffer of the consumer to be full. This would (as I understand it) cause the socket write method to block.

I am still learning about socket programming and I am not sure if my analysis above makes sense. If so, what might be a good way of determining which scenario it is? One thing to note is that the consumer is on a Linux machine, but the publisher is a Windows machine. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can measure how much time the receiver spends in the `read()` or `recv()` method, or whatever it is calling to read from the network.

If it is very little, there is always data banked up, so it is the receiver's fault for being slow to read.

If the time blocked in read is significant, it is the network's fault for being slow.

Comment: That is something that I have thought of, but the language I use on the consumer (q) has built in ipc running over TCP, and is event based, meaning I have no control over timing the read method. Having said this, I did manage to use the netstat command to see the Recv queue for this process, and it shows consistently 0. I have also benchmarked the consumers processing function which seems to indicate that it should be able to handle more load. This leads me to believe that it likely is the publisher that cannot push messages fast enough.

Comment: Well that amounts to the same thing. Its socket receive buffer is usually empty. So it isn't allowing data to back up. So it is the network or the publisher. Have a look at the state of the publisher's send buffer.

Comment: Indeed. I am trying to figure out how to check the size of the send buffer in windows.

Comment: (Not downvoter) The performance of read and recv is most likely not the issue here. I would have a look at the traffic. Try and capture the traffic on the sender and receiver and look at them in wireshark. If there is a lot of loss the senders congestion control might limit the throughput.